# array of Parent and children relationship

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I have a category array which consists of parents and children. can somebody help me arrange the array in the hierarchy using parent_id and category_id with foreach loop. The topmost Parent has a parent_id of "zero ". Please ignore other fields except category_id and parent_id. Here is my array.

```
Array
(
    [categories] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [workspace_id] => 1
                    [category_id] => 1527
                    [category_name] => CABIN
                    [category_description] => a seperate cabin
                    [capacity] => 100
                    [category_price] => 50000
                    [status] => 1
                    [created_by] => 1
                    [created_time] => 2017-07-14 07:56:54
                    [updated_by] => 1
                    [updated_time] => 2017-07-14 07:56:54
                    [label_id] => 1
                    [parent_id] => 0
                    [is_parent] => 0
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [workspace_id] => 1
                    [category_id] => 1528
                    [category_name] => C3
                    [category_description] => 
                    [capacity] => 
                    [category_price] => 
                    [status] => 1
                    [created_by] => 1
                    [created_time] => 2017-07-14 07:56:54
                    [updated_by] => 1
                    [updated_time] => 2017-07-14 07:56:54
                    [label_id] => 1
                    [parent_id] => 1527
                    [is_parent] => 0
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [workspace_id] => 1
                    [category_id] => 1529
                    [category_name] => FLOOR3
                    [category_description] => 
                    [capacity] => 
                    [category_price] => 
                    [status] => 1
                    [created_by] => 1
                    [created_time] => 2017-07-14 07:56:54
                    [updated_by] => 1
                    [updated_time] => 2017-07-14 07:56:54
                    [label_id] => 1
                    [parent_id] => 1528
                    [is_parent] => 0
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [workspace_id] => 1
                    [category_id] => 1530
                    [category_name] => CABIN
                    [category_description] => 
                    [capacity] => 
                    [category_price] => 
                    [status] => 1
                    [created_by] => 1
                    [created_time] => 2017-07-14 07:56:54
                    [updated_by] => 1
                    [updated_time] => 2017-07-14 07:56:54
                    [label_id] => 1
                    [parent_id] => 0
                    [is_parent] => 0
                )

            [4] => Array
                (
                    [workspace_id] => 1
                    [category_id] => 1531
                    [category_name] => C3
                    [category_description] => 
                    [capacity] => 
                    [category_price] => 
                    [status] => 1
                    [created_by] => 1
                    [created_time] => 2017-07-14 07:56:54
                    [updated_by] => 1
                    [updated_time] => 2017-07-14 07:56:54
                    [label_id] => 1
                    [parent_id] => 1530
                    [is_parent] => 0
                )

            [5] => Array
                (
                    [workspace_id] => 1
                    [category_id] => 1532
                    [category_name] => FLOOR1
                    [category_description] => 
                    [capacity] => 
                    [category_price] => 
                    [status] => 1
                    [created_by] => 1
                    [created_time] => 2017-07-14 07:56:54
                    [updated_by] => 1
                    [updated_time] => 2017-07-14 07:56:54
                    [label_id] => 1
                    [parent_id] => 1531
                    [is_parent] => 0
                )

            [6] => Array
                (
                    [workspace_id] => 1
                    [category_id] => 1533
                    [category_name] => CABIN
                    [category_description] => 
                    [capacity] => 
                    [category_price] => 
                    [status] => 1
                    [created_by] => 1
                    [created_time] => 2017-07-14 07:56:54
                    [updated_by] => 1
                    [updated_time] => 2017-07-14 07:56:54
                    [label_id] => 1
                    [parent_id] => 0
                    [is_parent] => 0
                )

            [7] => Array
                (
                    [workspace_id] => 1
                    [category_id] => 1534
                    [category_name] => C5
                    [category_description] => 
                    [capacity] => 
                    [category_price] => 
                    [status] => 1
                    [created_by] => 1
                    [created_time] => 2017-07-14 07:56:54
                    [updated_by] => 1
                    [updated_time] => 2017-07-14 07:56:54
                    [label_id] => 1
                    [parent_id] => 1533
                    [is_parent] => 0
                )

            [8] => Array
                (
                    [workspace_id] => 1
                    [category_id] => 1535
                    [category_name] => FLOOR1
                    [category_description] => 
                    [capacity] => 
                    [category_price] => 
                    [status] => 1
                    [created_by] => 1
                    [created_time] => 2017-07-14 07:56:54
                    [updated_by] => 1
                    [updated_time] => 2017-07-14 07:56:54
                    [label_id] => 1
                    [parent_id] => 1534
                    [is_parent] => 0
                )

            [9] => Array
                (
                    [workspace_id] => 1
                    [category_id] => 1536
                    [category_name] => CABIN
                    [category_description] => 
                    [capacity] => 
                    [category_price] => 
                    [status] => 1
                    [created_by] => 1
                    [created_time] => 2017-07-14 07:56:54
                    [updated_by] => 1
                    [updated_time] => 2017-07-14 07:56:54
                    [label_id] => 1
                    [parent_id] => 0
                    [is_parent] => 0
                )

            [10] => Array
                (
                    [workspace_id] => 1
                    [category_id] => 1537
                    [category_name] => C3
                    [category_description] => 
                    [capacity] => 
                    [category_price] => 
                    [status] => 1
                    [created_by] => 1
                    [created_time] => 2017-07-14 07:56:54
                    [updated_by] => 1
                    [updated_time] => 2017-07-14 07:56:54
                    [label_id] => 1
                    [parent_id] => 1536
                    [is_parent] => 0
                )

            [11] => Array
                (
                    [workspace_id] => 1
                    [category_id] => 1538
                    [category_name] => FLOOR2
                    [category_description] => 
                    [capacity] => 
                    [category_price] => 
                    [status] => 1
                    [created_by] => 1
                    [created_time] => 2017-07-14 07:56:54
                    [updated_by] => 1
                    [updated_time] => 2017-07-14 07:56:54
                    [label_id] => 1
                    [parent_id] => 1537
                    [is_parent] => 0
                )

            [12] => Array
                (
                    [workspace_id] => 1
                    [category_id] => 1539
                    [category_name] => CABIN
                    [category_description] => 
                    [capacity] => 
                    [category_price] => 
                    [status] => 1
                    [created_by] => 1
                    [created_time] => 2017-07-14 07:56:54
                    [updated_by] => 1
                    [updated_time] => 2017-07-14 07:56:54
                    [label_id] => 1
                    [parent_id] => 0
                    [is_parent] => 0
                )

            [13] => Array
                (
                    [workspace_id] => 1
                    [category_id] => 1540
                    [category_name] => ABOVE SBI
                    [category_description] => 
                    [capacity] => 
                    [category_price] => 
                    [status] => 1
                    [created_by] => 1
                    [created_time] => 2017-07-14 07:56:54
                    [updated_by] => 1
                    [updated_time] => 2017-07-14 07:56:54
                    [label_id] => 1
                    [parent_id] => 1539
                    [is_parent] => 0
                )

            [14] => Array
                (
                    [workspace_id] => 1
                    [category_id] => 1541
                    [category_name] => FLOOR2
                    [category_description] => 
                    [capacity] => 
                    [category_price] => 
                    [status] => 1
                    [created_by] => 1
                    [created_time] => 2017-07-14 07:56:54
                    [updated_by] => 1
                    [updated_time] => 2017-07-14 07:56:54
                    [label_id] => 1
                    [parent_id] => 1540
                    [is_parent] => 0
                )

            [15] => Array
                (
                    [workspace_id] => 1
                    [category_id] => 1542
                    [category_name] => Launch Pad
                    [category_description] => 
                    [capacity] => 
                    [category_price] => 
                    [status] => 1
                    [created_by] => 1
                    [created_time] => 2017-07-14 07:56:54
                    [updated_by] => 1
                    [updated_time] => 2017-07-14 07:56:54
                    [label_id] => 1
                    [parent_id] => 0
                    [is_parent] => 0
                )

            [16] => Array
                (
                    [workspace_id] => 1
                    [category_id] => 1543
                    [category_name] => C5
                    [category_description] => 
                    [capacity] => 
                    [category_price] => 
                    [status] => 1
                    [created_by] => 1
                    [created_time] => 2017-07-14 07:56:54
                    [updated_by] => 1
                    [updated_time] => 2017-07-14 07:56:54
                    [label_id] => 1
                    [parent_id] => 1542
                    [is_parent] => 0
                )

            [17] => Array
                (
                    [workspace_id] => 1
                    [category_id] => 1544
                    [category_name] => FLOOR3
                    [category_description] => 
                    [capacity] => 
                    [category_price] => 
                    [status] => 1
                    [created_by] => 1
                    [created_time] => 2017-07-14 07:56:54
                    [updated_by] => 1
                    [updated_time] => 2017-07-14 07:56:54
                    [label_id] => 1
                    [parent_id] => 1543
                    [is_parent] => 0
                )

        )

)
```

Comment: Can you share your expected output?

Comment: It will helpful if you give us your expected results

Comment: The outer most array should be of parent_id "0". Inside it there has to be children based on parent_id . The parent_id is nothing but the category_if of its parent. @SahilGulati

Comment: @ArigiWiratama Now the array is totally random with category_ids, what i need to do is arrange the array based on parent_id. The outermost array should be parent_id 0, The array should be multi dimensional with parent_id hierarchy

Answer (score 0):

Consider function

```
function get_childs($arr, $parent_id = 0) {
    $res = array();
    foreach ($arr as $row) {
         if ($parent_id == $row['parent_id']) {
              $childs = get_childs($arr, $row['category_id']);
              $row['childs'] = $childs;
              $res[] = $row;
         }
    }
    return $res;
}
```

Then use this function to get parents and it childs

```
$res = get_childs($arr);
```